# Magento 2 : Please upgrade your database while database is newer than required

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration, database-schema

I am getting this error when moving Magento 2 website to Google Cloud (Click to Deploy).

- I have merged theme files and media files and it worked fine. When I
  have connected to my old database it says this error.

[image: Error]

- I have tried these commands

  ```
  1) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  2) php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  3) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
  4) php bin/magento indexer:reindex
  5) php bin/magento cache:clean
  6) php bin/magento cache:flush
  ```

I am new here. and this is my first question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento2 can't handles backwards compability in modules.

I'd suggest installing https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2 and running `sys:setup:downgrade-versions`.

The alternative to this is going to the table `setup_module` and changing the versions.

Comment: **Thanks Man!** You're faster than machine!

Comment: some issues just pop up everyday and the solution is in the back of my head ;-)